Create a paraboloid and a right circular cone opening upward, with vertex at the origin
I want to create the following figure.

Here is my try for the paraboloid.
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
[
scale=1,
  axis lines=center,
  axis on top,
    samples=30,
    ticks=none,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z=x^2+y^2$},
    domain=-2:2,
    colormap/violet,
  ]

    \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.3,domain=-2:2] {x^2+y^2};  

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

However how can I remove the facets and get the appearance of the attached figure?
Here is my code for the cone.
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
    scale=1,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top,
    ticks=none,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    samples=30,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    y domain=0:2,
    zmax=2,
%    z buffer=sort,
    colormap/violet,
  ]
    
    % Cone surface plot
    \addplot3[surf, opacity=0.5] 
      ({y*cos(deg(x))}, {y*sin(deg(x))}, {y}); % Parametric equation of the cone
    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The same question here as well.

Hi @Dimitri ANAGNOSTOU!  I answered the questions Shading 3D arrows with conical tips; maybe you can find something useful in there, at lest for the cone.  Of course, you can also use pgfplots.
